# Finite rank volterra operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I am wondering when a Volterra integral operator $V_K:L_2(0,1)\to L_2(0,1)$ is a finite rank operator:

$$V_Kf=\int_0^xK(x,y)f(y)dy$$

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: A rank one operator on any Hilbert space is of the form $T(f) = \langle f,g\rangle h$. So what kind of kernel does that lead to?

Comment: I think this way will not lead to any result, since the kernel and the integral is of different kind. The integral is taken over a non-specified range from zero to $x$

Comment: $$\int_0^x = \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,x]}$$

Comment: so it means that when the kernel is separable, i.e. $K(x,y)=f(x)\times g(y)$, the operator $V_K$ is one rank operator, But what about a kernel in general?

Comment: @SaraWinslet This is an interesting question. Where it comes from? Is it an exercise from a book? Can you give a refernce, please?

Comment: @JankoBracic it is arisen from the question of whether the inverse of an differential operator is compact or not; is it possible for a Volterra integral operator to be compact while its range is infinite dimensional?

Comment: @SaraWinslet Yes, it is possible, the classical Volterra operator is of this type. In Halmos' Hilbert space problem book you can find basics about Volterra operators. Volterra operators are usually compact and quasinilpotent (the spectrum is just singleton $\{ 0\}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Volterra integral operator $V_K: L_2(0,1)\to L_2(0,1)$ which is given by
$$ (V_K f)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}K(x,y) f(y)dy\qquad (f\in L_2(0,1))$$
is of rank at most $n$ if and only if the kernel is of the form
$$ K(x,y)=g_1(x)\overline{h_1(y)}+\cdots+g_n(x)\overline{h_n(y)} \tag1$$
for some functions $g_j, h_j \in L_2(0,1)$ $(1\leq j \leq n)$ such that
$$ \chi_{[0,x]}(y)\bigl(g_1(x)\overline{h_1(y)}+\cdots+g_n(x)\overline{h_n(y)}\bigr)=g_1(x)\overline{h_1(y)}+\cdots+g_n(x)\overline{h_n(y)}, \tag2$$
i.e., the support of $g_1(x)\overline{h_1(y)}+\cdots+g_n(x)\overline{h_n(y)}$ has to be in the triangle $0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$.

For instance, let $a_1,\ldots, a_n \in (0,1)$ be arbitrary. Let, for each $j=1,\ldots, n$,
$$ g_j(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
0&; & 0\leq x<a_j\\
\gamma_{j}(x) &;& a_j\leq x\leq 1
\end{array} \right.\quad \text{and}\quad
h_j(y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
\eta(y)&; & 0\leq y<a_j\\
0 &;& a_j\leq y\leq 1
\end{array} \right. \tag3$$
where $\gamma_j\in L_2(a_j,1)$ and $\eta_j\in L_2(0,a_j)$. Then these functions satisfy (2). Of course, the kernel $K$ can have several representations of the form (1) which satisfy (2), however at least one of them is (3), I guess.